# How to get collect set in hive based on some conditions

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

How to get collect set in hive based on some conditions

```
id | num_of_cats
=====================
HOP            A

HOP            B

HOP            C

CAP            A

CAP            C

CAP            B

TOP            C
```

if indicator is A then first field is 1 . order is A,B,C
for eg:first row contain only A so indicators are 1,0,0
second row contain only B so indicators are 0,1,0

should return:

```
id | cats_aggregate    (indicator order is A,B,C)
===========================
HOP   Array<int>(1,0,0)

HOP   Array<int>(0,1,0)

HOP   Array<int>(0,0,1)

CAP   Array<int>(1,0,0)

CAP   Array<int>(0,0,1)

CAP   Array<int>(0,1,0)

TOP   Array<int>(0,0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
select id,
       array( (case when num_of_cats = 'A' then 1 else 0 end),
              (case when num_of_cats = 'B' then 1 else 0 end),
              (case when num_of_cats = 'C' then 1 else 0 end)
            )
from t;
```

Comment: could be simplified to `array((cast(num_of_cats='A' as int)),...)`